# Identity Monad - Behaviour difference in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, identity

I have recently been playing around with Monads in Haskell (still a relative beginner with all this). I came across some interesting behaviour (or at least interesting to me) with the `Identity Monad`.

---

If I write the following function:

`let f = \x -> Identity 2 >>= \y -> x * y`

and then do `:t` I get `f :: Num b => Identity b -> Identity b`. It is inferring that x is an `Identity (Num b)`. I am able to call the function with `6` and I get the result `12`.

However if I try the same with `Maybe` like so:

`let g = \x -> Just 2 >>= \y -> x * y`

```
<interactive>:2096:5: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (Maybe b)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        g :: forall b. Num (Maybe b) => Maybe b -> Maybe b
```

I therefore need to explicitly return `Maybe` or use `return`. So I do: `let g = \x -> Just 2 >>= \y -> return $ x * y`.

Everything works fine. However then I got to wondering what is happening with the `Identity` monad.

Firstly I tried adding the explicit return type like so:

`let f = \x -> Identity 2 >>= \y -> Identity $ x * y`

and then did `:t` again and I got `f :: Num b => b -> Identity b`. Which is what I was expecting the first time around.

---

Which made me wonder about how it was able to handle `x + y` without `Identity $` if it was inferring `x` and `y`to be wrapped inside an
`Identity`. So I tried the following:

`Identity 5` + `Identity 6` with the result being `11`

`Identity 5` + `6` with the result being `11` again

However it I try the same with `Maybe` like so

`Just 5` + `Just 6`

`Just 5` + `6`

I get the following error:

```
<interactive>:2116:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (Maybe a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Num (Maybe a), Num a) => Maybe a
```

I have tried `FlexibleContexts` but I just got the following error:

```
<interactive>:2134:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num (Maybe a0)) arising from a use of ‘it’
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

---

I was wondering if someone could shed a little light on why the `Identity` monad behaviour is different to `Maybe`?

Also is it possible to use `FlexibleContexts` to get the same behaviour with the `Maybe` monad? I haven't been able to get it to work as of yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `Identity` has a `Num` instance and `Maybe` does not (you can see the instances of a type by using `:i` in GHCi or looking [in the Hackage documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html#t:Identity)).

So, when you have `\x -> Identity 2 >>= \y -> x * y`, that `*` is actually the `*` from the `Num` instance for `Identity a` (where `a` is itself a `Num` instance, like `Int` or `Double`, etc).

Additionally, numeric literals in Haskell are polymorphic: `5 :: Num a => a`, so they can behave as any `Num` instance rather than being restricted to a specific one (like `Int` or `Double`). That is what's happening when you try something like `Identity 5 + 6`. The `6` is inferred to have type `Num a => Identity a`, since `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`.

You can see this more explicitly:

```
ghci> :t 5
5 :: Num p => p
ghci> 5 :: Identity Int
Identity 5
ghci> 5 :: Maybe Int

<interactive>:12:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num (Maybe Int)) arising from the literal ‘5’
    • In the expression: 5 :: Maybe Int
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = 5 :: Maybe Int
```

Comment: That's weird, I wouldn't expect `Identity` to have a num instance.  Why?  At this rate, why don't we add num instances for all applicatives?

Comment: @luqui That, I don't know. It's especially strange since I don't think `IdentityT` has those instances. Although, I'm not sure why you'd restrict to just applicatives, either way... I think the `Num` laws should be (vacuously) satisfied by something like `data VoidWithArg a` (where there are no constructors.

Comment: @DavidYoung It's kind of tricky to implement `fromInteger` for `VoidWithArg a`.

Comment: @luqui Applicative is actually not quite strong enough to guarantee the one `Num` law, namely, `abs x * signum x == x`. (Think of `[]`, or `Parser`.) I think last time I thought about this, I landed on `x *> x = x` being a plausible rule to distinguish those applicatives for which the obvious `Applicative`-based `Num` instance is law abiding and those for which it isn't, but I don't know of an existing class with that as a law.

Comment: @DanielWagner Are there any interesting `Applicative`s (ie not `Identity` or `Proxy`) for which `x *> x = x` holds? Struggling to think of any

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, there's `Reader`, but that's not interesting either. The most interesting I can think of is `Writer` with a monoid for which `forall x. x <> x = x`. Something like `Writer Any`, say.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson (and dfeuer, and Daniel Wagner): There is `Maybe`, if that counts as interesting. `x *> x = x` is a consequence of being what King and Wadler in [*Combining Monads*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.40.7571&rep=rep1&type=pdf) call an idempotent monad. (Note we might want to tweak that name -- not only because the property generalises straightforwardly to applicatives, but also because "idempotent monad" has a different meaning in categorical parlance.)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Most "zippy" applicatives (e.g. `Maybe` as duplode mentioned, `ZipList`, and the other container types that do zip-like things on `(<*>)`) satisfy that law.

Comment: Thanks, those are both good examples. (I feel like I should've been able to come up with them myself! Don't code tired, kids)